# SQL Table as parameter with IDBCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am experimenting how allow a web application to support multiple databases, specifically SQL Server and MySQL.

I've already setup my SQL helper class that will take care of connecting to the database and query execution. I'm am using `IDBCommand`, `IDBConnection`, etc. I've tested the class with a console application and it works just fine with queries without parameters.

But when I add in the parameters, that's where the problem starts.

I wish to use parameters for the table names because the current table names might change and it would be a pain to rename the tables in the queries.

I've found an article where the author shared his methods for adding parameters to `IDBCommand`. I can't find the link to the article but here's a sample of what I've gotten from the article (Thanks to the author btw! :D) I am able to confirm the parameters were added because they were listed under the `IDBCommand` by using QuickWatch but I am getting a "Must declare the table variable "@myTable"." error.

```
    internal static int AddInputParameter<T>(this IDbCommand cmd,
    string name, T value)
    {
        var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
        p.ParameterName = name;
        p.Value = value;
        return cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    }
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Edit:
In response to bew's reply, I was able to do this using both `SqlCommand` and `MySqlCommand`.

Edit2:
Looks like I've remembered wrong. I used `string.format()` for the table names in my past project.

Comment: im not sure in visual studio 2010 if it allows table to be populated by a parameter, in my case I used a variable instead

Comment: I was able to do this using SqlCommand.

Comment: you are returning int in the signature, when this method would return `SqlParameter` in the return statement?

Comment: I'm guessing it is as simple as adding in the `@` to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot pass a table as a parameter. Instead, any query where you want to determine the table at runtime must be assembled as a string before it is used in a parametrized query. The longer answer requires understanding what happens when you call something like `cmd.ExecuteReader` with a parametrized dynamic SQL statement. In that scenario, the .NET classes build a call using `sp_executesql`. For example:

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max);
Set @Sql = 'Select Count(*) From sys.objects Where object_id > @SomeNum';
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@SomeNum int', 10000;
```

Now suppose we try to insert a parameter for our table into the SQL statement. The resulting statement will be:

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max);
Set @Sql = 'Select Count(*) From @SomeTable Where object_id > @SomeNum';
exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@SomeTable nvarchar(256),@SomeNum int', 'sys.objects', 10000;
```

This will result in an error along the lines of `Must declare the table variable "@SomeTable"`. SQL Server doesn't know that `@SomeTable` is a parameter and not say a table variable. Thus, object references (tables, views, procedures etc.) are not something you can parametrize; only criteria can be parametrized.

Comment: While this is sql server-specific and the question is explicitly about supporting more than just sql server, the gist of the answer is right: you just can't pass table names as parameters. A better explanation of why is that most RDBM's process a query by first _compiling_ it (at some level) to produce some kind of execution plan. This step will also involve verifying that the connected user has appropriate permissions... if it doesn't know a hard table name, it can't determine that. Additionally, if it doesn't know a hard table name, it can't know how what indexes are available for the plan.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Although, isn't the compilation issue a factor of *when* it compiles? I.e., if it assembled the full SQL statement incorporating the use of parameter values and then compiled, it doesn't run into the issue. In the case of sp_executesql, it's compiling the parametrized statement and thus runs into the issues you mentioned. In the case of SQL Server, I can't imagine how it would even work compiling in any order other than what it already does.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help but here is a function I used a while ago.  It uses anonymous types to add parameters.  Feel free to use it as a template:

```
private static void Addparms(SqlCommand cmd, object parms)
{
  // parameter objects take the form new { propname = "value", ... } 
  foreach (PropertyInfo prop in parms.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + prop.Name, prop.GetValue(parms, null));
  }
}
```

It is then  called like this:

```
Addparms(cmdObject, new { name = "Hogan", page = 1, last = "Long" });
```

This will add 3 parameters `@name`, `@page`, and `@last`.